# Understanding Rabbitmq permissions

Tags: permissions, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, stomp

I'm attempting to set up a pub/sub system. My technical director has suggested using Rabbitmq and STOMP for the project I've been assigned.

In this system I want exchanges to be created on the server side and passed to the user to subscribe to. I want a user to subscribe to an exchange and receive information as it becomes available. I do not want the client to have the ability to subscribe to arbitrary exchanges (or routing keys for topic exchanges, I'm not sure what system I want to use yet).

For example, if someone works for a company widgetInk, when they logged in to our website they would receive a connection to the widgetInk.whatever exchange and AllUsers.whatever exchange, but that's it. if the Client side attempted to subscribe to something else they'd get an error.

[I've gone through all of the RabbitMQ tutorials and I've looked through their how to section.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) I found this [basic article on access control, but having read it three times now I still don't know if rabbitmq is a good fit for my requirements.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html)

Can Rabbitmq be configured for my requirements? What resources can I use to learn about Rabbitmq's permission system? Has anyone build or used a system like this? Would it be in my best interest to switch to ZeroMQ or ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to mention another platform you might use: [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws) (Open-Source) or [WebMQ](http://www.tavendo.de/webmq) (based on Autobahn).

WebMQ provides these features (besides a lot of other out of the box):

- PubSub over WebSocket ([WAMP](http://wamp.ws))
- Authentication of client sessions (WAMP-CRA)
- fine-grained configurable authorization for topics

If you want to go the Open-source/build-your-own road, here are some [tutorials](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp). If you want an integrated, commercially supported product with Web UI for configuration/administration, please get in contact.

Disclaimer: I am creator of Autobahn/WAMP and work for Tavendo.

Comment: I would actually give this a try if this was just my project. The problem I see with this is that I'm attempting to manage the server side with c/c++ since our main server client is written in c/c++ and whatever I choose will have to integrate with it. I know that Python can integrate with c/c++, but I'm fairly low on the totem pole and my company isn't used to python as a language.

Comment: RabbitMQ is written in Erlang. Tight integration between Erlang and C++ is possible (as with Python), but probably not trivial. Another thing is having a client in C++ that accesses the WebSocket server / PubSub message broker. Currently, there is no WAMP client library for C++. The latter would be possible with limited efforts when using a robust WebSocket library, such as WebSocket++ (C++/ASIO-based).

Comment: I'm currently trying to get the RabbitMQ-c plug in to work with my server side. I'll look into WebSocket++. My current solution stack is stomp.js || Sockjs.js || Rabbitmq-web-stomp || rabbitmq || rabbitmq-c. I'm very new to WebSockets and this project has been... interesting to research. Thanks for the alternative reading.